# Reload vaadin table

Tags: vaadin, reload

I have a Vaadin table in a View. There is a button to create a new row in the table, a subwindow opens which allows you to specify the new item and create it.
Once created a notification tells you it was created successfully, at this time I would like to reload the current UI (which is a View) so that the new element is visible (if pagination would make it visible).
I tried `UI.getCurrent().markAsDirty();` before closing the subwindow but it does not work.

Comment: Is this table immediate (`table.setImmediate(true);`)?

Comment: Do you have your own Container for the table? does it fire an itemSetChangeEvent after insertion?

Comment: you might try table.refreshRowCache()

Comment: The table is immediate. The method refreshRowCache does not work. The table has its own container, the problem here is that this container is filled in at the beginning of the enter method, and when the new item is created in the subwindow, the container should be entirely reloaded. I'm also considering the event mentioned in the second comment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem by taking advantage of the Table method addItem. This works, although there must be more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The vaadin table can be automatically reloaded by changing the main layout that you are using to static.

Comment: SO site provide relevant ans so provide ans with detail explanation,or some example

Answer (score 0):

I have just run into a similar problem. I had a table backed by sql, and a subwindow to edit details + delete. There was no update of the table, no matter of having markAsDirty(), setImmediate(true) on either subwindow or the table.

The solution was to get the SQLContainer from the table, and call refresh on that:

```
 Table table = new Table("Contact items");
 ... // add dataSource, headers etc, and after several calls:

 @Override
    public void windowClose(CloseEvent e) {
        SQLContainer c =  (SQLContainer)table.getContainerDataSource();
        c.refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just struggled along this problem. I used a PagedTable... extended by me, and added a method like this:

```
Object[] visibleColumns = getVisibleColumns();
getDataSource().refresh();
setContainerDataSource(getContainerDataSource()); 
setVisibleColumns(visibleColumns); 
refreshRowCache();
```

This way I could use a popup for inserting a new item into a Table, and get the Table refreshed with the new line.(There were some additional code to page where the new record can be seen)

Answer (score -1):

If you want just to refresh the table, you can use the table container data source to do this refresh by remove all items and add again, just like the following code:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
for(Object object : table.getContainerDataSouce().getItemIds()){
    items.add(table.getContainerDataSource().getItem(object));
}

table.getContainerDataSource().removeAllItems();
table.removeAllItems();

items.add(<yourItem>);

for(Item item : items){
    table.getContainerDataSource().addItem(item);
}
```

Comment: If that table had ten thousands of rows, how fast would removing and re-adding them all be? There must be a better solution than this.

Comment: Vaadin is an UI display framework, good luck having ten thousands of rows stored in memory and displayed to the user.

Comment: If your software uses a web front end, 'AG Grid' is a very good solution, plus it is very well documented. See https://ag-grid.com/